# PHP Session variables available one one page, but not another...

Tags: php, session

Almost got my login scripts working, got a strange issue with the session variables though. I create the session variables which running the login code in

> ./includes/functions.php

For some reason they don't exist on that same page, as my check_login function is also on the functions.php page. But when I do the check it fails:

```
function login_check($mysqli) {
    //Check if session variables are met
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['email'], $_SESSION['login_string'])) {
```

I have another page called process_login.php which is in

> ./php/process_login.php

The session variables work here, as I get the correct information from the following code

```
<?php
include "../includes/db_connect.php";
include "../includes/functions.php";
include "../includes/required.php";

if(isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = hash('sha512', $_POST['p']); //Encrypted password

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        //Login success
        echo "Logged in!";
        //header("Location: ".ROOT."index.php");;
    } else {
        //Not user found
        echo "Not user found with those details";
    }
}
?>
<h1>You are logged in as <?=$_SESSION['email']?>!</h1>
<h2>Your user ID is: <?=$_SESSION['user_id']?>.</h2>
<h2>You have <?=$_SESSION['perms']?> rights.</h2>
```

This is my login script which creates the session variables

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    //Use prepared statements to stop SQL Injection
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, email, password, salt, perms FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email); //Bind "$email" to paramater
        $stmt->execute(); //Execute the query
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $email, $db_password, $salt, $perms); //get variables from result
        $stmt->fetch();
        $password = hash('sha512', $password.$salt); //hash the password with the unique salt

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) { //If user exists
            //Check that user account isn't locked
            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                //Account is locked, alert user
                return false;
            } else {
                if ($db_password == $password) { //Check that passwords match
                    //matches, create session
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; //Create hash with password and user agent
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512',$password.$user_browser);
                    $_SESSION['perms'] = $perms;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else { 
        //Error
        echo "Prepare failed: (".$mysqli->errno.") ".$mysqli->error;
    }
}
```

It could be an issue with my session script, which is below. Is this script even needed or could I simply use

> session_start();

I'm using the script to make it a bit more secure.

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'ppa_session_id'; //Custom session name
    $secure = false; //Set to true if using https
    $httponly = true; //Stops JavaScript being able to access session id

    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); //Force current cookie params

    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); //Gets current cookie params
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
    session_name($session_name); //Sets the session name to the custom one
    session_start(); //Start the session
    session_regenerate_id(); //regenerate the session, delete the old one
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

every page that has $_SESSION[''] in it needs to have session_start(); on top of the page just after opening php

Comment: Just noticed that the page that the session variables are available on didn't have my custom session start script. If I add that script the session variables no longer work again.

Comment: The script from the guide i'm following regenerates the session ID everytime it is called, which at first I thought was the issue. But I created a session variable on a page, refreshed, then removed the code but the session variable was still available after another refresh and the session id had been regenerated... :S

Comment: That's because session_regenerate_id only affects the session and not the variable $_SESSION. Unless you have a good reason to use this script, you could just keep it simple and use session_start at every page. p.s I'm not sure but i do think it does delete the variable $_SESSION if you use session_regenerate_id(true); p.p.s otherwise you could use unset($_SESSION); to make the session variable unavailable

Comment: Ah okay, the guide says that's more secure (this web application will only be on local machines anyway but would be nice to have a secure user system) is it? Or will the simple session_start() do ?